# Using dynamic Wicket-Resources the right way

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to create a simple application based on wicket. I want to place a Panel on my page which indicates if the user is logged in. 
Sadly, I was unable to find a working example of my problem: I want my Label to display the username if someone is logged on and some message, if no user is logged on.
I guess I'm missing something.

Here comes the code:

Panel:

```
public class Header extends Panel {

IModel<StringResourceModel> userNameModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<StringResourceModel>() {

    @Override
    protected StringResourceModel load() {
        final User user = MySession.get().getAuthenticatedUser();
        if (user==null){
            return new StringResourceModel("username.noUser", Header.this , null);
        }else{
            return new StringResourceModel("username.user", Header.this, Model.of(user));
        }
    }
};

public Header(final String id) {
    super(id);
}

@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();
    add(new Label("username", userNameModel));

}

}
```

Properties:

```
username.noUser=You are not logged in
username.user=Welcome, ${name}
```

Markup:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <wicket:label class="username" wicket:id="username" />
</wicket:panel>
```

The rendered text is

> StringResourceModel[key:username.noUser,default:null,params:[]]

The behaviour makes sense. But how can I fix it so the desired text is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the String from the `#load()` method:

```
IModel<String> userNameModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {

    @Override
    protected String load() {
        final User user = MySession.get().getAuthenticatedUser();
        if (user==null){
            return new StringResourceModel("username.noUser", Header.this , null).getObject();
        }else{
            return new StringResourceModel("username.user", Header.this, Model.of(user)).getObject();
        }
    }
};
```

Note the call to `StringResourceModel#getObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a deeper look at the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization) and chose the following approach:

```
public class Header extends Panel {

    private static class UserState {
        private final String userLoggedIn;
        private final User user;


        public UserState(final User user) {
            super();
            userLoggedIn = user==null?"noUser":"user";
            this.user = user;
        }
        public String getUserLoggedIn() {
            return userLoggedIn;
        }
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

    }

    IModel<UserState> userModel         = new LoadableDetachableModel<UserState>() {

                                         @Override
                                         protected UserState load() {
                                             return new UserState(HouseSession.get()
                                                     .getAuthenticatedUser());
                                         }
                                     };


    public Header(final String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();
        final StringResourceModel messageModel = new StringResourceModel("username.${userLoggedIn}", Header.this, userModel);
        add(new Label("username", messageModel));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        userModel.detach();
    }

}
```